# How to fix the jsinterop error in Telerik Report viewer in Blazor using Visual Studio 2022 .Net 7

Tags: telerik, blazor-server-side, telerik-reporting

I have been working with Blazor and Telerik and following the course on the Telerik site but when I tried to integrate the Telerik Reporting by using Telerik report viewer component according to the course, it did not show the report in the browser and didn't gave any error in the terminal of Visual Studio as well. Generally the website is working fine but only the report page isn't working and shows these errors in the browser console. I even set up a completely new project to check the difference but even in the new project the report viewer  isn't showing anything and is showing the same error.
Some extra information if needed it, I am using:
**Visual Studio 2022,
Blazor server app,
.net7,
Telerik latest trial version**.
Here  are the images of errors and code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Uninstall the **Telerik reporting setup** from Control panel
[image]

Step 2: Go to the Visual Studio **Tool>Nuget Package manager>Package manager setting**
[image]

Step 3: Package Manager window will open in **General** and c**lick on Clear All Nuget Storage**
[image]

Step 4: reinstall the Telerik reporting and open your project remove all the telerik packages and reinstall them.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it looks like your script references are correct, although it is hard when you have attached images instead of code. It will be more useful for the next person with the same issue and for those who try to help you, if you add the code instead of pictures. I have tested with the latest Trial packages and the Blazor item template and I was not able to reproduce your issue.

My guess is that the error "Could not find telerikReportViewerInterop.createReportViewerWidget" is connected with the SSL settings as I see such error in your screenshot, that was not present in my project, although I used certificate. You can try with new project with http setting or fix the SSL.
There is also a small possibility that the issue is connected to your namespaces/routes.

There is a [knowledge base article](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/knowledge-base/could-not-find-telerik-report-viewer-interop) for this error, but I do not think it applies to your code, anyway you can check it out, it is short.
Just for a test you can try to remove the defer from the interop script reference and see if the error is still appearing.

Maybe there is an issue with your NuGet packages. You can try to uninstall and install them again or uninstall the product, restart the machine and install the product. Deleting the NuGet cache may also help. You can check if there are any errors for the dependant NuGets or any other errors when using the item template. You can also try opening your project on another computer and check if there are errors.

Comment: i have already tried the link you suggest thanks any way here is the sample project in which i have same error https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Aa4EB65XTEokjZwsvQl89ejtxFmsK_X1/view?usp=sharing         hope so it will help to solve my problem

Comment: i also tried your SSL suggestion the SSL error gone away but the main error is still the same.

Comment: It took me some time to spin up a virtual machine and install software that can open rar files. It is better to share GitHub repo than sharing some file, that can potentially contain viruses. 
Your project works as expected on my side. The viewer and the report are loaded.
Maybe there is an issue with your NuGet packages? Can you try to uninstall and install them again? Deleting the NuGet cache may also help. Are there any errors for the dependant NuGets? Any other errors when using the item template? You can also try opening your project on another computer and check if there are errors.

Comment: can you post this as an answer or should i post all the steps i have done first i have resolve the SSL error but it didn't resolve the issue and i think it was not the main issue at all because i have an other running project which was working fine . But i think the Telerike nuget package maybe the problem in this case because from the first installation to until now i have resolved many issues regarding the packages installation.

Comment: but today when created a new project after reinstalling every thing that one work fine and after remove the packages from the existing one and reinstalling it also work fine .

Comment: I am glad the issue is gone! I added the NuGets info to my post. Of course post yourself whatever you think may help somebody else.